# In php how to read the csv file using excel and know the data format of the each columns

Tags: php, excel, csv, dataformat

I have some csv file and want know the data format i.e data type of the csv columns .its not possible from direct csv file .so that i would like to read a csv file in micro soft excel and know the data format of each columns. i need to done these steps using php.

Is there any way?

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible to determine the types using plain PHP? It's very much possible as long as you know for sure that each column doesn't have mixed types (i.e.: a column with one row as a number and another row as a string)

Comment: yeah each columns have unique format like number,string,etc.but i try this method var_dump() and gettype() both returning the each columns is string.

Comment: @JYoThI did you get an answer for this.

Comment: sorry i didn't get answer for this . @rahul