# A column of csv file giving wrong data type while reading row by row

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to import csv file's data into MySql through PHP. Why i'm getting all the column values datatype as string. Actually the columns are numeric like 23, 34, 5, etc.. Here is my code in which i'm trying to read the csv file:

```
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   echo gettype($data['column']); // i'm getting type as string
 }
}
```

Actually the $data['column'] is integer value but i'm getting it as string. What i'm trying to do is to validate those columns according to there data type.

Comment: did you try `is_numeric()` function?

Comment: all the columns in the csv file is coming as "string" datatype

Comment: it doesn't matter, if you check `is_numeric("23")` it will return `true`. And you can insert it in databse in a `INT` field even the value you are trying to import is a string, it must only be a number

Comment: @TeoMihaila before touching the db i want to validate the data, but all the numbers, string and everything is coming as a string. My requirement is if the column value integer, it should validate for integer or otherwise something else.

Comment: This is exactly my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028023/in-php-how-to-read-the-csv-file-using-excel-and-know-the-data-format-of-the-each

Answer (score -1):

Type cast the specific column that you want to convert it into int data type. 
e.g in php you can do some thing like 
$int = (int)$data[‘column’];
echo $int.

Comment: I'm getting all the column gettype as string. if number is there it should return integer otherwise some other datatype like that.